# Microsoft Exchange compatible desktop email client on Mac with selective folder sync?

Tags: email-client, synchronization, microsoft-exchange

I'm looking for a free desktop email client on Mac that supports both Microsoft Exchange accounts and allows me to selectively sync certain folders. I have all my emails from 2010 in the Archives folder on my Exchange account, and these are clogging up my hard drive's disk space. I don't want to permanently delete my old emails, but also don't need them to be downloaded to my hard drive.

- Mac Mail doesn't allow me to selectively sync certain folders.
- Thunderbird is discontinued and doesn't integrate with Exchange accounts. The ExQuilla plugin would allow this, but is not free.
- Outlook has a whole host of problems on Mac (even the 2016 version), not least the fact that it can't selectively sync folders.

Is anyone aware of an option that will allow me to achieve all of the above?

Note that I am not looking for integration with any features of Microsoft Exchange other than email support (i.e. I am not interested in Calendar support).